# CoreData's NSFetchrequest: Provide classname and propertynames moredynamically

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, introspection

In CoreData, when you want to query for an object, you have to specify the name of the entity and the names of the properties in strings like that:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name=%@ AND Forename=%@", name, vorname];
```

I don't really like this approach, because in doing so, the IDE can't help me in scenarios like renaming one of the properties or renaming the classname.

Using this code-block, I made my call a little more dynamic by getting the classname by introspection:

```
NSString *classname = [[Person class] description];    
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:classname inManagedObjectContext:context];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name=%@ AND Forename=%@", name, vorname];
```

Is there any way to get the name of the properties (Name and Forename) the same way?
I don't know how to handle properties dynamically.

Do you get my point? I'd be happy, if someone could point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've used plists in the resource bundle in this way, sort of-- basically, create an `NSDictionary` that maps keys that are your parameters to the names of the properties on the object at hand, then just name it `MyClassname.plist` for easy loading into memory. You'd have to write one up for every class you want this for, though. (and edit them if you change the property names)

Not sure if there is an easier way.

And, IIRC, you sub in the keys as so:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%k=%@",[plist objectForKey:@"param1"],[personObject valueForKey:[plist objectForKey:@"param1"]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to me, that it is quite usual, to pass strings containing the property-name as method-arguments.
I'm new to Objective-C working usually in c#. Using LINQ, you can define queries easily where you filter elements by their properties.

    `IEnumerable<Person> result = allEntities.Where(p=> p.Name == name && p.Forename == forename);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I see a big advantage of `entityForName:[[Person class] description]` over `entityForName:@"Person"` (or maybe `entityForName:PersonEntityName` where PersonEntityName is just a constant). It works fine provided that the name of the class that represents an entity is the same as the name of the entity, but that's often not the case. It's quite common to use plain old NSManagedObject for simple entities, and that obviously doesn't match the entity name.

Likewise, if you're creating a fetch request, the names of the properties that you're interested in are usually already determined and unlikely to change, so specifying them by name is usually the easiest thing to do. You can get an array of properties from the entity description, but how will you know which property to use if you don't already know its name? And if you know the name of the property, there's not much sense in retrieving the property description just so you can get its name. ;-)

There are times when it's helpful to leave the entity and properties undetermined until the application runs, such as when you want to let the user specify the parameters of the search. That's clearly not the case in the example you gave, though, because you've given the format of the predicate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think, it actually makes sense - at least to me ;-) Think of it as converting runtime-errors into design-/compile-time errors.

Comment: I could understand if that really let you catch errors earlier, but I don't see how it does that. Using `[[Person class] description]` instead of `@"Person"` doesn't reduce the chance that the name "Person" won't match the name of the corresponding entity, and the compiler won't catch that error in either case.

Comment: Thanks, I get your point. I need to think this through. But from my experience in c#, I hate to write propertynames in strings ;-) In a refactoring-process, these things will always mess up.